# How to select a subject from a transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I downloaded an image which has a transparent background. The subject has lots of feathering around the edges so selecting the background with the magic wand leaves a substantial gap. How do I remove this gap?

[image]

Comment: It kinda depends on what you actually want from it... if you simply want to place it somewhere else, you could `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+C`... And then `Ctrl+V` to paste it somewhere. — If you want to make a perfect selection off of a layer that has transparency/translucency, then simply `Ctrl+left click` the layer thumbnail. — On Mac replace `Ctrl` with `Cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

1, I create a similar situation as yours, with empty area selected:
[image]

2, Refine Edge, change view mode as:
[image]

3, increase Contrast to counter to blurry, don't make it total clear, just make it near clear:
[image]

4, now push Shift Edge to the right, till you satisfied (depends on how much you want to keep, see step 6), then maybe adjust Contrast a little:
[image]

5, ctrl+shift+i to invert selection, ctrl+j then you get it:
[image]

6, Now you get edge corrected, but inside the edge the cloth has lost details. Here's a trick, ctrl+j 10 or 20 times, you'll get back details near perfect, then you could do step 1~5 again (with subtle values) to get a perfect clear edge.